# Date to time Friday 19 may 2017 and compare with date now

Tags: php

I have the following date and i want to compare this with the date off today.

How can i achieve that?

```
if( Friday 19 may 2017 < date now ){
    do smething
}
```

Comment: In what instance can that ever evaluate to `true`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple use strtotime() function

Read http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

```
if( strtotime('Friday 19 may 2017') < strtotime('now') ) {
    echo 'do something';
}
```

Or (edited because BenM comment)

```
if( strtotime('Friday 19 may 2017') < time() ) {
    echo 'do something';
}
```

Comment: `strtotime('now')` === `time()`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class in PHP:

```
$date = new DateTime('2017-05-19 00:00:00');
$now  = new DateTime();

if( $date < $now ) 
{ 
    // Do your stuff.
}
```

However, since you're dealing with a specific date, surely it will always be in the past?